# springjdbc template does not return alias column name of table

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss

I am upgrade jboss server from jboss 4.0 to jboss 7.0 . but in jboss 7.0 alias name query does not work properly.

there is one name query in our xml file

```
<query>
    SELECT t.status_id AS id, t.code 
    FROM sme..status_types as t
</query>
```

and we are use below method to call this query

```
List result = null;
result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(namedQuery.getQuery());**
```

when deploy our application on **jboss 7** it provided below output

jdbc server query result : `[{**status_id=1**, code=SUB}]`

here you can see alias column is not coming so here we got error because we fetch the record base on alias column

but when we run the same query on jboss 4 it's return below result
jdbc server query result : `[{**id=1**, code=SUB}]`

we are using sybase as database

can you anyone suggest what this query is not return alias column name

Comment: You migrated servers and thus have probably a different datasource configuration (assuming it comes from JNDI). Make sure you are using the same driver version between jboss versions.

Comment: we just upgrade the jboss version and there is not any change in data source also result is coming from database but not reflect the alias name

Comment: There is something different either the used driver or the configuration. Spring just delegates to the JDBC driver.

Comment: we define data source in standalone file and using spring jdbc template to execute the query

Comment: Please read. The fact that your configuration didn't change doesn't mean JBoss might not ship/require a newer JDBC driver. This might lead to different behavior. Something apart from your JBoss has changed, and I suspect it is the JDBC driver version for Sybase. Or you didn't configure it exactly as you did in your previous `standalone.xml` and the new one.

Comment: Also JBoss itself ships with Hibernate, if you use Hibernate to execute the queries that might have an impact as well (unless you are shipping Hibernate within your application instead of using the version provided by your server).

Comment: the drive is configure correctly and we are used jconnect4.jar and document also mentioned the same https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SYBCON/jConnect+Driver+Overview and we can't use jboss with hibernates itself because we are using thrid party framework jar